# Is it possible to turn the noise or music off?

Tags: super-mario-party

When playing super mario party I went to play "Mario Party" mode and every time it is my turn to use the dice, a noise comes from the joy-con (i think) is there anyway to turn the music/sound that plays when it's your turn?

It may not be a problem to people, but it's kinda annoying to me becouse I prefere to play games without noise, it's not the vibrate I am talking about, I mean the sound/music.

I play it docked/on tv and the tv volume is all the way down.

Comment: What system are you playing on? You say “joy-con (I think).” Could this actually be a Wii remote and nunchuck?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to disable the sounds that come from the joycon without disabling vibration in general. Looking at Nintendo's [tech specs](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/features/tech-specs/) for the Joy-Cons, there's no mention of speakers at all. Going online and searching for "joycon speaker", I can see that other games use the "HD Rumble" feature to essentially produce sound via haptic feedback, which is very likely what is happening here.
Probably the closest you could get is disabling vibration in general, and Nintendo does provide [instructions](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22721/~/how-to-activate%2Fdeactivate-hd-rumble) for that.